Why Visual Studio 2022 set MyProjectName before 'My.Resources' in designer file?
i'm having an issue in designeer file on winforms project after Visual Studio 2022 update. When i add a resource like an image in form Visual studio set the image like 'MyProjectName.My.Resource.image'. If i remove 'MyProjectname.' project is build correctly otheerwise not like in the image attached.
Could someone help me?
This thing drives me crazy, thanks a lot
enter image description here
I searched on forums but nobody helped me. If i remove manually all errors as soon as modify form design Visual studio re-edit all the name

This seems to be broken in .NET Core (tested with .NET 8).
How to fix:

In the Solution Explorer enable the button "Show All Files".
In the Solution Explorer select the file MyProject > Resources.resx
In the Properties window set:

Custom Tool = ResXFileCodeGenerator
Custom Tool Namespace = My


In the Solution Explorer right click MyProject > Resources.resx and Run Custom Tool from the context menu.

Now a file Resources.Designer.vb should be associated with Resources.resx and your resources will be available under My.Resources. The designer now inserts e.g. PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Image1.

Thanks for the help but the problem persists.
i have no more idea about this. All my project have the same issue after visual studio update

It seems i resolved take off the namespace from default name space.
Now i can edit forms design without problems.

